# SSH Port forwarding with Bash on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-10, bash, ssh, port-forwarding

I've recently migrated from Mac OSX to Windows 10 and am getting an error when attempting to mirror the ssh local port forwarding setup in my **~/.ssh/config** file as follows:

```
host myhost
HostName myhost.mydomain.com
Port 9005
LocalForward localhost:3680 myhost:3680
User manachi
```

This works fine on OSX - I can just **ssh myhost** to connect. However when attempting on Bash on Windows, I get the following error:

```
bind: Address already in use
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3680
```

Can anyone advise what the issue/workaround for this is?

Comment: Getting this to work in windows would be quite messy, given the way Bash on Windows currently runs. I believe you can't do what you're trying to do with it at this moment in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first **localhost** in the **LocalForward** statement to 127.0.0.1 to force IPv4 protocol, because in Windows localhost is bound to IPv6 address ::1

`LocalForward 127.0.0.1:3680 localhost:3680`